# Have you written very long functions? If so, why?

Tags: c, code-metrics

I am writing an academic project about [extremely long functions in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127588/why-are-some-functions-extremely-long-ideas-needed-for-an-academic-research).

For that purpose, I am looking for examples for real-life functions that are extremely long (few hundreds of lines of code), that you don't consider bad programming (i.e., they won't benefit from decomposition or usage of a dispatch table).

Have you ever written or seen such a code? Can you post or link to it, and give explanation of why is it so long?

I have been getting amazing help from the community here - any idea that will be taken into the project will be properly credited.

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: You should probably make this community wiki, as this is a personal question.

Comment: He won't do it. And he is now posting dupes, which is not likely to help his research project. See his other posts for evidence.

Comment: Right you are. I see you even made the same suggestion in one of his earlier topics.

Comment: Wasn't this asked yesterday or the day before?

Comment: Made it community wiki. Didn't mean to duplicate; The previous questions were different. However, if you believe I should close or delete the question - I will do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The longest functions that I have ever written all have one thing in common, a very large switch statement. There are times, when you have to switch on a long list of items and it would only make things harder to understand if you tried to refactor some of the options into a separate function. Having large switch statements makes the Cyclomatic complexity go through the roof, but it is often better than the alternative implementations.

Comment: `it would only make things harder to understand if you tried to refactor some of the options into a separate function` I agree, but what about using a list of cases and a list of function pointers and mapping them?

Answer (score 4):

It was the last one before I got fired.

Answer (score 3):

A previous job:  An extremely long case statement, IIRC 1000+ lines.  This was long before objects.  Each option was only a few lines long.  Breaking it up would have made it less clear.  There were actually a pair of such routines doing different things to the same underlying set of data types.

Sorry, I don't have the code anymore and it isn't mine to post, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The longest function that I didn't see as being horrible would be the key method of a custom CPU VM. As with @epotter, this involved a big switch statement. In fact I'd say a lot of method that I find resist being cleanly broken down or improved in readability involve switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't often find this type of subroutine checked in or posted somewhere if it's auto-generated during a build step using some sort of code generator.

So look for projects that have C generated from another language.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the performance, I think the size of the call stack in Kernel space is 8K (please verify the size). Also, as far as I know, code in kernel is fairly specific. If some code is unlikely to be re-used in the future why bother make it a function considering function call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that when speed is important (such as when holding some sort of lock in the kernel) you would not want to break up a function because of the overhead due to making a functional call. When compiled, parameters have to be pushed onto the stack and data has to be popped off before returning. Therefor you may have a large function for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Perhaps, but as Neil commented before - inlining is the answer to this problem.